# javascript stripe add items with if

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I cant seem to get the list of items created dynamically, i want to add additional items, but only if a value is true

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
items: [{
    plan: plan, 
    quantity: quantity,
},
{
    plan: 'plan_ddddddd0Hxlu', 
    quantity: aditionalStorageDays,
}],
successUrl: 'https://example.com/success',
cancelUrl: 'https://example.com/cancel',
customerEmail: '<?php echo $userInfo['email']?>',
}).then(function (result) {
// If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
// error, display the localized error message to your customer
// using `result.error.message`.
});
```

How do i add the secound item only if aditionalStorage is true?

```
{
    plan: 'plan_ddddddd0Hxlu', 
    quantity: aditionalStorageDays,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more... 
You mean you want to push the object into array?
Or you want to splace the existing object and then push the new one ?